# Google Colab upload word embeddings

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab for my DL model (NLP), I uploaded and imported my training data (screenshot) and now I'd like to pre-train on GloVe word embeddings. If I upload the same way, it will take hours I guess, and even then I'm not sure if it works.

Did anyone come across the same problem?

Thanks

**uploading training data**
[image: screenshot: uploading training data]

Answer (score 4):

Try to wget it directly

```
!wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip
```

Comment: Interesting. I did not mount my G-drive? Where does the zip file gets stored? Is this persistent?

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the file on my drive and then imported it from the google drive

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
file_id = 'your file id '

import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
  # _ is a placeholder for a progress object that we ignore.
  # (Our file is small, so we skip reporting progress.)
  _, done = downloader.next_chunk()

downloaded.seek(0)
glove=format(downloaded.read())
```